# c# Reducing the number of methods used to get data from a DB

Tags: c#, methods, code-reuse

I have a Class that processes DB column metadata. One of the Properties of the Class is the table in question. This is passed to the object via the constructor. Also in the constructor I apply some logic to assign other variables within the class. To do this there are a number of private methods that connect to a DB, query something about the table, and return a value to the variable.

My problem is that I have a lot of different methods doing pretty much the same thing, but returning a different datatype. So for example my code is something like this

```
public Column(string tableName)
{
   strTableName = tableName;
   pkColumnName = GetPKColumnName(tableName);
   pkColumnLenght = GetPKColumnLenght(tableName);
}

private string GetPKColumnName(string tableName)
{
   string query = String.Format("SELECT myColName FROM myTable where myTableName = {0}",  tableName);
   string result = "";
   try
   {
       using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
         {
          con.Open();
          using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
          {
             result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
          }
         }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
 return result;
}

private int GetPKColumnLenght(string tableName)
    {
       string query = String.Format("SELECT myColLenght FROM myTable where myTableName = {0}",  tableName);
       int result = 0;
       try
       {
           using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
             {
              con.Open();
              using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
              {
                 result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
              }
             }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     return result;
    }
```

There are many other methods like this also. This didn't look great to me, so I was wondering what the best practice was for something like this.

Should I just declare the return type as an object and do the datatype conversions when assigning the returned value to my variable?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Should I just declare the return type as an object" most likely not.  Define a class that encapsulates the `Name` and `Length` and return that.

Comment: You should use parameter based queries, to avoid sql injection or other issues. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `SqlManager` class

```
public class SqlManager
{

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return "Your ConnectionString"
        }
    }

    public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd.Connection == null)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            return conn;
        }

        return cmd.Connection; 
    }

    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
           throw;
        }
        finally
        {
           conn.Close();
        }
   }

}
```

Now your methods, for the second one same thing:

```
private string GetPKColumnName(string tableName)
{
    string query = String.Format("",  tableName);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT myColName FROM myTable where myTableName = @TableName";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tableName);

    object result = SqlManager.ExecuteScalar(cmd);

    return result != null ? (int)object: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer and the other assume different questions.  It appears to me that you are trying to query a single value from a specific column and that you have to create a new method because the types are different.  That said, I would personally just use a simple ORM solution and the other answer certainly is not wrong, just another abstraction.

You will want to use generics and cast to the generic.

I haven't tested this code, it is more of a guideline.

```
private T GetValue<T>(string tableName, colName)
{
   string query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM myTable where myTableName = {1}", colName, tableName);
   T result = default(T);
   try
   {
       using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
         {
          con.Open();
          using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
          {
             result = (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
          }
         }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: curious why the downvote, it succinctly answers the question he asks without assuming too much

Comment: This is open to SQL injection - I'd expect the application to only pass in constants to the method, but building dynamic SQL where you pass in things to inject is still subject to mistakes or maliciousness. In addition to fixing the `myTableName` parameter to be a SQL parameter, the safe way to do this without a lot of extra work (although it would be slightly slower) is to do a `select *`, then retrieve the appropriate value with a `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: while certainly true, do you think that you are assuming that this has a UI?  I didn't read anything about that

Comment: UI or not, it's a bad pattern to have a method which builds SQL all willy-nilly based on arbitrary input. Otherwise you've got a piece of code which is vulnerable if someone comes in and writes some good unit tests, or if it's ever ported to something that does have a UI. Another issue, which is probably solvable by adding square brackets, is that SQL keywords like `From`, or multi-word column names will fail here. I think square brackets would solve that every time, but it's still something else to consider.